# Kafka connection could not be established. Broker may not be available

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, connection, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

Docker containers connect on start to each other succesfully. But after some time an error occured in "connect" container

> Connection to node -1 (broker/172.27.0.3:29092) could not be
> established. Broker may not be available.

Docker-compose file:

```
 version: "2.4"
    ### Common settings section ###
    x-common: &common
      logging:
        options:
          max-size: "1m"
          max-file: "10"
      env_file: .env
      restart: unless-stopped
    # network_mode: "host"
    
    services:
    
      zookeeper:
        <<: *common
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.0
        hostname: zookeeper
        container_name: zookeeper
        ports:
          - "2181:2181"
        volumes:
          - zookeeper_data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
        environment:
          ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
          ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    
      broker:
        <<: *common
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.0.0
        hostname: broker
        container_name: broker
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
        ports:
          - "29092:29092"
          - "9092:9092"
          - "9101:9101"
        volumes:
          - broker_data:/var/lib/kafka/data
        environment:
          KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
          KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
          KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
          KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
          KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
          KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
          KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
          KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
          KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
          KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
          KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
    
      schema-registry:
        image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.0.0
        hostname: schema-registry
        container_name: schema-registry
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
          - broker
        ports:
          - "8081:8081"
        environment:
          SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
          SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
          SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
    
      connect:
        <<: *common
        build:
          context: ""
          dockerfile: Dockerfile-connect-custom
          args:
            CP_VERSION: 6.0.0
        hostname: connect
        container_name: connect
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
          - broker
          - schema-registry
        ports:
          - "8083:8083"
        environment:
          CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
          CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
          CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
          CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
          CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
          CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
          CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
          CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
          CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
          CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
          CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
          CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
          CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
          CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
          CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
          CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
          CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
          # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
          CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-6.0.0.jar
          CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
          CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
          CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
          CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR
    
      rest-proxy:
        <<: *common
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:6.0.0
        depends_on:
          - schema-registry
          - broker
        ports:
          - 8082:8082
        hostname: rest-proxy
        container_name: rest-proxy
        environment:
          KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
          KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
          KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
          KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
    
    volumes:
      zookeeper_data:
      broker_data:
```

Dockerfile-connect-custom:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:6.0.0
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-mysql:1.3.1
```

How to fix this error? What is wrong in setup?